form array inside mat table created inside an observable
i have a parent component : Parent List contains two child components (first-child list , second-child list )
in the second child list component : i have a mat table that receive the data to display as input data so i create the data Source in the ng OnChanges with the  instance of Mat Table Data Source), i use the selection Model to handle the selection row (iuse isAllSelected and master Toggle methods ).
i need to pass the selected rows to the first child component , i use service that contains behaviour subject so i next the data by using the set Data methods .
in the first child component i use the form Array inside the mat table and i handle the selection ,  do a console log of data Source ( you see in console that when i play with the selection one or many or all in the second list component i have like a loop in console and it takes a time to select all or one in the second list component , may be because i create a table inside the subscribe methods )
you can found my stack-blitz contains the code here ,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-frcek7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent-list%2Fparent-list.component.html
try to play with select and we can see that takes a few time and loop so many times in console

Grammar matters.

You have this.setData() in isAllSelected() method. It causes multiple executions of .next of your subject.
isAllSelected() is triggered on every change detection multiple times in your template
        [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
        [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"

if you remove this call of this.setData() from isAllSelected you'll see only one console log
update:
in your masterToggle you also trigger selection change for each item in table which causes your subject to next for each row.
You can fix it by replacing
this.dataSource.data.forEach((row: any) => this.selection.select(row));

into this
this.selection.select(...this.dataSource.data);

so that it triggers selection change in one go

if you open the stackblitz in the web and do a console i always have a lot of console ( loop many times ) in the first child list Side bar , t dosnt work correctly for me

did you read and fix all i wrote?
